# Request.getParameterValues returns null when not in IE5 quirks mode

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsp, quirks-mode

I have a jsp page that always sends a list of 20 items back to my Java controller. Basically I have an id value that gets incremented but gets assigned to 20 items of the same name.

jsp:

```
<input type="text" style="display: none" name="displayId" id="<%=displayId%>" value="<%=displayId%>">
```

Where I set the display id above. Then in the back end after the page is submitted I call this code to grab the items.

```
String[] displayIds = request.getParameterValues("displayId");


    for (String i: displayIds)
    { ...do some other stuff
```

My issue is that the displayIds array is null after the page is submitted. I want to move away from IE5 quirks mode so the page will run on other browsers. Is there another more "standard" way I can go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like my issue has to do with how the jsp page is set up. There are 2 nested forms on the page and it looks like the initial design was to submit it and then grab the ids from request.getParameterValues() I was able to take the outer form and move it so that the tags aligned correctly and then used a for loop to loop over the values (the for loop with dispalyIds is simply to add on an incrementing integer at the end of the requested value) then used request.getParameter("name"+i) inside the for loop to get the values I needed.

I then no longer had any null values and was able to save. Hope this helps someone.